# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location') in res.redirect

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I have the following function to retrieve an object from a database and extract an URL:

```
async redirect(id: string, redirectFunction: Function) {
    if (!IdExists(id)) {
      throw new Error(`ID ${id} does not exist.`);
    }
    const redirectLocation: string = await prisma.url.findUnique({
        where: { uniqueId: id },
        select: { url: true },
    }).then((data) => {
        return data?.url!;
    });

    redirectFunction('http://' + redirectLocation); 
}
```

The function is called in the following segment of code:

```
app.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      redirectController.redirect(req.params.id, res.redirect);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } 
});
```

However, I get the `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')`, I see that the error is related to the `res.redirect` method. However, when I replace it by `console.log` for debugging, the URL is showed properly. What may be causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code:

```
redirectController.redirect(req.params.id, res.redirect);
```

Passes `res.redirect` (a function reference) as the second argument, but all that is passed is just the function so the `res` gets lost when you later try to call it.  That causes the method to have a wrong `this` value when it executes and lots of things go wrong.

You can fix that several different ways.  Once such way is with `.bind()`:

```
redirectController.redirect(req.params.id, res.redirect.bind(res));
```

`.bind()` creates a small stub function that remembers the value of `res` so that when the stub function is called, it will be called with the right `res` reference and thus the `this` value inside the function will be correct.

Another way to solve it is to create your own little stub function:

```
redirectController.redirect(req.params.id, (...args) => {
   res.redirect(...args);
});
```

When it calls your stub function, you call `res.redirect()` properly and pass it whatever arguments the controller called your stub function with.

---

As a small demonstration, you can see this effect here:

```js
const obj = {
    greeting: "Hello",
    talk: function() {
        if (this && this.greeting) {
            console.log(`this.greeting is "${this.greeting}"`);
        } else {
            console.log("value of this is wrong");
        }
    }
}

console.log("calling as obj.talk()");
obj.talk();                             // works

console.log("-------------------------");

// function we pass a method to and then call that method
function callTalk(fn) {
     fn();
}

console.log("calling by passing method to another function");
callTalk(obj.talk);                     // doesn't work

// call it using .bind()
console.log("-------------------------");
console.log("calling using .bind()");
callTalk(obj.talk.bind(obj));           // works
```

Comment: Added an additional solution with your own stub function.